# DNS forwarding settings: Can I use a DNS name server as target of A entry?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, nameserver, cname

I have a site hosted on Webhostingpad and my domain is registered on Godaddy.

In my account at Godaddy I have it set to use the Webhostingpad name servers: `NS1.WEBHOSTINGPAD.COM` and `NS2.WEBHOSTINGPAD.COM`.

This means the CNAME that maps `www.mysite.net` to `mysite.net` is provided by the Webhostingpad nameserver rather than Godaddy.

But now I want a new subdomain to direct to a new address (my home server that uses a dynamic DNS service). So I want to make a new CNAME entry somewhere that maps `homesubdomain.mysite.net` to `myaccount.dyndns.com`.

I could do this by setting this CNAME from Webhostingpad but I'm wondering how to do this by setting this CNAME at Godaddy. Can I make an A entry for my naked domain that goes to `NS1.webhostingpad.com`? Does it make any sense to do this? If not, how can I get the Godaddy name server to forward only specific sub domains (or the naked domain) to webhostingpad?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. Name service for your domain is controlled from the name servers for your domain. If you don't want to change them, then you have to change the name settings on those servers.

Comment: Can you explain what this page means? http://www.webhostingpadreview.org/webhostingpad-dns-domain-nameserver

Comment: That page is telling you how to have your DNS controlled by Webhostingpad. If you want them to control your DNS, you'll have to configure it all with them. If you don't, then ignore that page and configure it somewhere else.

Comment: How might I go about configuring it elsewhere? I notice that when I go to my site's server's IP, it directs to a different website! This seems to indicate that perhaps they are directing to particular ports based on the domain requested. Does this mean I'm screwed? Look here: http://domaintz.com/tools/overview/69.65.33.11 262 sites are hosted on this IP. What is the mechanism that powers this?

Comment: Okay I found out that HTTP/1.1 allows this with the `host` header. So can I still just do the CNAME and A with different DNS servers and it would work?

Comment: No. You need to pick the DNS servers that you're going to use for your domain and configure your DNS at those servers. Follow these steps: 1) Decide which DNS servers you want to use. 2) Set it up so those DNS servers provide the responses you want. 3) Change your DNS servers with your registrar to be the ones you picked.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I have also read this article and it has made it clear how the system works. http://ottopress.com/2010/how-not-to-let-dns-bite-you-in-the-ass/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup CNAME for specific hostname at GoDaddy, change authoritative nameservers back to GoDaddy's default nameservers. Then, add CNAME record of `homesubdomain.mysite.net` in DNS Manager of GoDaddy.

To use hosting of Webhostingpad, ask them IP of web server (Mind it, its not IP of nameservers).

- If they provide you IP of web server, use it to create A record for any subdomain or naked domain in DNS Manager of GoDaddy.
- If they don't provide you IP of web server, create NS records of subdomains in DNS Manager of GoDaddy. E.g. create two NS records for `subdomain` hostname pointing at `ns1.webhostingpad.com` and `ns2.webhostingpad.com`. Remember, you can't create NS record of naked domain. To workaround it, you can host website at www (turn off CNAME at Webhostingpad) and HTTP redirect naked one from GoDaddy's DNS Manager. But, you can't use webhostingpad's email service (if its provided on naked domain).

That's it!

Comment: Thanks. This helps. So far it's been working great as I have the naked domain forwarded to the IP of my webhostingpad server and I can direct other subdomains to any other machines I want.